# How to merge this release branch to the master?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I was using this project to test all types of delete operation and ended up in the current situation. Now when I try to merge from release to master, it always give me "Git apply failed with code 1: checking patch error does not exist in index" error when I try to stage the hunk.

What shall I do at this point?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your branches `master` and `release` are not connected, so you cannot merge. But if the image is not misleading and the two commits on `master` are effectively the same commits as the first two commits on your `release` branch, then just reset your `master` branch to your `release` branch by doing `git branch -f master release`.